# perform IO inside wai application

Tags: haskell

I am following the basic dispatching section of wai application.

I am able to catch the url parameter. How can I perform IO operation using these params.

I would like to use `runCommand` of System.Process to execute a system command using these parameters.

:t runCommand give 
`runCommand :: String -> IO ProcessHandle`

my Main.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where
import Control.Monad
import Network.Wai
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import Data.ByteString
import Control.Monad
import System.Process
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L8

main :: IO ()
main = do
    run 8080 app

app :: Application
app request respond = respond $ case rawPathInfo request of
    "/" -> indexHtml 
    "/wake" -> wakeMeUP request
    _ -> fourNotFour

indexHtml :: Response
indexHtml = responseFile
    status200
    [("Content-Type","text/html")]
    "index.html"
    Nothing

wakeMeUP :: Request -> Response
wakeMeUP request = 
    let query = queryString request
        hour = join $ lookup "hour" query
        min = join $ lookup "min" query
    --I would like to use runCommand "using hour and min variables"
    in responseLBS
        status200
        [("Content-Type","text/plain")]
        "Alarm set at...to be coded later"

fourNotFour :: Response
fourNotFour = responseLBS

    status404
    [("Content-Type","text/plain")]
    "404 not found"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design prevents it, because of how you have written `app`,

```
app request respond = respond $ case rawPathInfo request of
```

which says that you immediately respond.  Note the type of [`Application`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.1.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Application):

```
type Application = Request -> (Response -> IO ResponseReceived) -> IO ResponseReceived
```

Since the result type has an `IO`, you have the opportunity to do I/O before yielding a value.  So you could:

```
app request respond = do
    whateverResult <- runCommand "whatever"
    respond $ ...
```

*(You could also do it afterward, at least according to the types:*

```
app request respond = do
    rcvd <- respond $ ...
    runCommand "whatever"
    return rcvd
```

Though that's a bit odd to do for the continuation-passing idiom being used here (the `(a -> b) -> b` pattern in the `Application` type).  It means that the command will be run after everything else, for some definition of "everything else" that we can't know without reading the `wai` source.)

Anyway, you probably don't want the command to be run inside `app`, but rather in `wakeMeUp`, which means you need to change some types around.  In particular,

```
wakeMeUp :: Request -> IO Response
--                     ^^
```

and suitably monadify the function.  Then your `app` needs to not call `respond` immediately, so you can say

```
app request respond =
   response <- case rawPathInfo request of
       "/" -> return indexHtml
--            ^^^^^^
       "/wake" -> wakeMeUp request
--       no change, because wakeMeUp now has an IO return type
       ...
   respond response
```

If this is gibberish to you, it's time to do some monad tutorials. Or if you just want to get the damn thing working, I recommend Dan Piponi's [The IO Monad For People who Simply Don't Care](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html). Happy hacking!

Comment: Thanks. It makes perfect sense. I reached to similar solution after posting the question. But In my code I had to loos the route code. I understand monads but I realised I need to do more exercise of IO.